# Separate LI's by child element

Tags: html-agility-pack

i have the following code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodeCollection = bodyNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='myClass']//li");
```

which grabs about 250 `LI`'s

the `UL` format is a bit weird and it goes like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h5>Parent</h5>
        Some more tags here...
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Child of the prev li</h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Child of the prev li</h4>
    </li>
    <!-- and so on -->
    <!-- Then again -->
    <li>
        <h5>Parent</h5>
        Some more tags here...
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Child of the prev li</h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Child of the prev li</h4>
    </li>
    <!-- child li's are not constant, this is only for demo -->
</ul>
```

i need to separate the `LI`'s into groups where each group contains the parent `LI` and all the children `LI`'s

anyone can help with this?

Comment: So all `li` tags have somewhere written (not necessary in <h5>) that they are parent? and you want to have `List<HtmlNode>` with parent li's?

Comment: no, the `li` are visually separated into groups, when an `li` with an `h5` is the header of the group, then the next `li`s are childs, until there is again an `li` with an `h5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is want you want

```
HtmlNodeCollection liList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul//li");
List<List<HtmlNode>> liGroups = new List<List<HtmlNode>>();
List<HtmlNode> liGroup = null;
foreach (HtmlNode li in liList)
{
    if (li.InnerText.Contains("Parent"))
    {
        if (liGroup != null)
            liGroups.Add(liGroup);
        liGroup = new List<HtmlNode>();
        liGroup.Add(li);
    }
    else
    {
        liGroup.Add(li);
    }
}
liGroups.Add(liGroup);
```

What you will have at the end is a list `liGroups` that will have other list `liGroup`. For your above html it will show that `liGroups` have 2 `liGroup` because in your above html you have 2 parents and both two `liGroup` will have 3 li (1 parent + 2 childs) because both parents have same amount of children.

After that you do with them whatever you want for example:

```
MessageBox.Show(liGroups[0][2].InnerText); //Show from the first group the 3rd's li InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var tree = new Dictionary<HtmlNode, List<HtmlNode>>();
foreach (var node in nodeCollection)
    if (node.SelectSingleNode("h5[text()='Parent']") != null)
        tree.Add(node, new List<HtmlNode>());
    else
        tree.Last().Value.Add(node);
```

or

```cs
var groups = nodeCollection.Group();

static class Extensions
{
    public static ILookup<HtmlNode, HtmlNode> Group(this HtmlNodeCollection collection)
    {
        return collection.Where(n => !n.IsParent()).ToLookup(n => n.GetParent());
    }

    public static bool IsParent(this HtmlNode node, string header = "Parent")
    {
        var h = node.Element("h5");
        return h != null && h.InnerText == header;
    }

    public static HtmlNode GetParent(this HtmlNode node)
    {
        while (!node.IsParent())
            node = node.PreviousSibling;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant rely on the text of `h5 since it is different in each h5, it was only for example.

Comment: @Dementic then how do you distinguish between parents and children list items in a flat collection? Some text, some class, instance counter, etc? Use that to implement `IsParent`.

Comment: That is exactly the problem, i cant distinguish between them.
i was thinking about a recursive function, will try to write one.

Comment: @Dementic sorry, but this doesn't make sense. What makes one li a parent? How would you, as a human, mentally decide "ok, this is a parent, others are its childrens", are they rendered differently?

Comment: lol, dont ask me, i am only trying to scrape this weird page.
as i said at start, the problem is with the weird markup of the ul.